# accessing the property of a child from the parent and passing such property to another component in flex

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I have a component A which has two components B and C. Now, component B has a child component D which has an XML property. The task now is how can i pass the XML property from D  to the C component?

Answer (score 0):

You can either say C.xmlProperty = D.xmlProperty in your A component or you can dispatch a custom event with data from your D component and listen for that event in your C component.
If you want more specifics, please show me some example code so that i can help you more.

all the best, 
blz

Comment: hi @Anton Petrov, i got that problem solved yesterday using the propertyDocument of the parent class to pass the xml from D to B and then just did data binding by passing xml from B to C

Answer (score 0):

You should create and dispatch a custom event which contains that XML. You can read more about custom events [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf67fe7-7ffd.html). So D dispatches your event to B. B can process data and finally redispatches it to A. Or you can use event bubbling and listen to this event from D directly in A. The disadvantage of the second way with bubbling is impossibility to declare a contract (using metatags) and impossibility to handle events in MXML.

Comment: hi @constantiner, i got that problem solved yesterday using the propertyDocument of the parent class to pass the xml from D to B and then just did data binding by passing xml from B to C

Comment: You shouldn't call parent's properties or methods form child directly (I mean parents and children in terms of composition). It is a strongly bad practice. Avoid it in any case. This way your components are very coupled and OOP practices are all about low coupling. So using Observer pattern with Flash event model is the best solution for you.